Swift Twilio Conversations, how to create/save a TCHMessage?
In Twilio in Swift, is it possible to encode, or save to defaults (which requires it to be encoded anyway), or create a TCHMessage? I really need to experiment with TCHMessages, in order to develop the app. The problem is, how to decode it, after having encoded one message object? I need to hardcode somehow, or create a TCHMessage, but I couldn't do it. I couldn't do it because Codable saves only the properties, so I cannot recreate the original TCHMessage.
Also, creating the TCHMessage from scratch (using a constructor) is not very convenient, because it is very difficult to make (I actually don't know how). Do you? Thanks for sharing.
